# ASP.Net Hiddenfor incorrect values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm developing ASP.Net WebApp and facing a trouble sending POST request back to my controller.

When I select a provider in a textbox, my hiddens look like do not show correct values. ProviderId value is **[object Object]** and ProviderName is **""**

Do you have any idea whats wrong there?

```
<input data-rule-number="true" data-rule-required="true" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ProductProviderId must be a number." data-val-required="The ProductProviderId field is required." id="account-provider" name="Provider.ProductProviderId" type="hidden" **value="[object Object]"** aria-required="true">
<input data-rule-number="true" data-rule-required="true" id="account-provider" name="Provider.Name" type="hidden" **value=""** aria-required="true">
```

Here is a view:

```
...
<div class="form-group property-hide provider-search">
    <label for="account-provider-search">Provider Search:</label>
    @Html.TextBox("providersearch", String.Empty,
        new
            {
                    id = "account-provider-search",
                        data_rule_required = "true",
                        data_enhancer = "autocomplete",
                        data_url = "/overview/providersearch",
                        placeholder = "Enter provider here",
                        @class = "form-control"
                })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Provider.ProductProviderId, new { id = "account-provider", data_rule_required = "true", data_rule_number = "true" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Provider.Name, new { id = "account-provider", data_rule_required = "true", data_rule_number = "true" })*@

</div>


My classes look like:

public class ManualAccountViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public ProviderModel Provider { get; set; }
}
public class ProviderModel
    {
        public int ProductProviderId { get; set; }
        public int PartyId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the values you put in Id and Name are correct? What happens if you just write them out on the page? Because i doubt Razor is printing those values.

Comment: @VDWWD They are correct because the textbox shows them

Comment: How are you sending them? A `Html.BeginForm`? An ajax POST?

Comment: @JamesS AJAX POST

Comment: And I am assuming that when you go into Google DevTools and look at the variables, they have the correct result?

Comment: Just checked them and they look correct

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the same ID twice. ID's MUST be unique and I believe in this case, especially from what I can see here, you have the following for example:

```
<input data-rule-number="true" data-rule-required="true" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ProductProviderId must be a number." data-val-required="The ProductProviderId field is required." id="account-provider" name="Provider.ProductProviderId" type="hidden" **value="[object Object]"** aria-required="true">
```

has ID `account-provider`

then further down you have a hidden for with the same ID.

There is no way the application can determine which one you want. Changing the value of this ID should show the correct results I beleive.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help. With ID `account-provider` at least ProviderId value is set to [object Object]. But when I change the ID to i.e. `account-provider-id` fields value becomes empty.